# How to make a column non-editable in Kendu UI Grid?

Tags: kendo-grid

How do I make a column (auto generated) non-editable in Kendo UI Grid?
One way that I can think of, is by using custom HTML Editor and making it read-only or disable but I was expecting it to be out-of-the-box feature?

Am I missing something, shouldn't it be a property or something?

Thanks,
Avi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are usign inline editing then this must help you:
Set that field as editable:false in the schema.

```
               schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "sr_id",
                        fields: 
                        {
                            card_number: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                            merchant: { editable: true, type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `fields` options for the model, make every column `editable: false`, except the one you want to edit: `editable: true`

And in the options for the grid, have `editable: true`.

It works.